# Paste bracketing causes slow pastes

Tags: zsh, paste, oh-my-zsh, iterm

When I paste in large blocks of text, or even just long commands or urls, **pasting is done character by character and takes a long time**. I can make it speed up by pressing right arrow but that sometimes autosuggest will then come in and paste other things.

I know this is caused in part by **paste bracketing**. I tried turning it off which makes it about the speed it goes when I press right arrow during a slow paste. But then indents aren't preserved and it executes line by line. This doesn't work for me since I regularly paste in multiline commands like with Docker for example. Also, syntax highlighting doesn't work anymore when using the right arrow technique.

**Is there a way to make pasting instant but preserve the bracketing behavior?** In vim it's instant but I guess indents are just newline characters or something I guess? Is bracketing even causing this problem or is there some other explanation/fix?

I'm using **iTerm2** with **ohmyzsh** and **Powerlevel10k** on **MacOS Catalina**. Searched high and low but only found posts about the ~0 and ~1 characters being inserted with bracketing or something. I never had that happen.

A gif for illustration purposes:

https://i.imgur.com/vFL0gmL.mp4

Comment: As romkatv answered on Reddit, you have to set `DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"` at the top of you .zshrc. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Just disable magic functions in `.zsh`.

Uncoment `DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"`

Comment: Curious to know if this just disables paste bracketing or will it disable other functionality too. I searched for "zsh magic functions" but wasn't able to find much.